# Remove values from array which exist in other array

Tags: php, arrays

I am having two array. in PHP

```
dir(0=>1,1=>2,2=>3,3=>5,4=>7,5=>8);
list(0=>1,1=>12,2=>18,3=>20,4=>7,5=>8);
```

Resulting array should be

```
result(0=>2,1=>3,2=>5);
```

the result array should contain the values which is not exist in list() array

Answer (score 1):

```
$diff=array_diff($dir,$lists);
```